# Save the current state of program and resume again from last saved point

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I have a script to download images from a link. Suppose the script gets terminated due to some reason then I want to save the point till which the images have been downloaded and resume again from the point last saved

I have made the download script and tried saving the state of the program using pickle till now

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
import os,time,random,pickle
import csv
data=pd.read_csv("consensus_data.csv",usecols=["CaptureEventID","Species"])

z=data.loc[ data.Species.isin(['buffalo']), :]

df1=pd.DataFrame(z)

data_2=pd.read_csv("all_images.csv")

df2=pd.DataFrame(data_2)

df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='CaptureEventID')

p=df3.to_csv('animal_img_list.csv',index=False)

# you need to change the location below
data_final = pd.read_csv("animal_img_list.csv")
output=("/home/avnika/data_serengeti/url_op")

mylist = []

for i in range(0,100):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    mylist.append(x)

print(mylist)

for y in range(len(mylist)):
    d=mylist[y]
    print(d)

file_name = data_final.URL_Info
print(len(file_name))
for file in file_name:
    image_url='https://snapshotserengeti.s3.msi.umn.edu/'+file
    f_name=os.path.split(image_url)[-1]
    print(f_name)
    r=rq.get(image_url)

    with open(output+"/"+f_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    time.sleep(d)


with open("/home/avnika/data_serengeti","wb") as fp:
    pickle.dump(r,fp)

with open("/home/avnika/data_serengeti","rb") as fp:
    pic_obj=pickle.load(fp)
```

Suppose i have to download 4000 images from a URL. I successfully downloaded 1000 images but due to some network issue my script crashed. So i want that when the script restarts then it should start downloading from image number 1001. Currently it starts fresh from image number 1 again if the script is restarted. How can i run my loop again after loading the pickle object?

Comment: I don't think it is possible but what you can do is, check the filename of the image, if it is already downloaded then skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple solutions to this problem but this comes first in mind it will help you to solve this problem.

**Approach :**

It's very clear, the script starts to download from starting because it can't remember the index till where it has downloaded the last time.

To solve this issue we will create a text file which is having an integer 0 denoting to that up to this index file has been downloaded. And when the script runs it checks what is the integer value present in the text file. (It's like recalling the position). The value in the text file gets incremented with 1 if the file is downloaded successfully.

**Code**

An Example for understanding ::

Please See: I have manually created a text file with '0' in it earlier.

```
# Opening the text file
counter =  open('counter.txt',"r")

# Getting the position from where to start.Intially it's 0 later it will be updated
start = counter.read()
print("-->  ",start)
counter.close()

for x in range(int(start),1000):
    print("Processing Done upto : ",x)

    #For every iteration we are writing it in the file with the new position      
    writer = open('counter.txt',"w")
    writer.write(str(x))
    writer.close()
```

Fixing your code :

Note: Create a text file manually with the name 'counter.txt' and write '0' in it.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
import os,time,random,pickle
import csv
data=pd.read_csv("consensus_data.csv",usecols=["CaptureEventID","Species"])

z=data.loc[ data.Species.isin(['buffalo']), :]

df1=pd.DataFrame(z)

data_2=pd.read_csv("all_images.csv")

df2=pd.DataFrame(data_2)

df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='CaptureEventID')

p=df3.to_csv('animal_img_list.csv',index=False)

# you need to change the location below
data_final = pd.read_csv("animal_img_list.csv")
output=("/home/avnika/data_serengeti/url_op")

mylist = []

for i in range(0,100):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    mylist.append(x)

print(mylist)

for y in range(len(mylist)):
    d=mylist[y]
    print(d)

# Opeing the file you manually created with '0' present in it.
counter =  open('counter.txt',"r")
start = counter.read()
count = start
counter.close()

file_name = data_final.URL_Info
print(len(file_name))

# The starting position from the file is used to slice the file_name from 'start' value.
for file in file_name[start:]:
    image_url='https://snapshotserengeti.s3.msi.umn.edu/'+file
    f_name=os.path.split(image_url)[-1]
    print(f_name)
    r=rq.get(image_url)

    with open(output+"/"+f_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

    # File is downloaded and now, it's time to update the counter in the text file with new position.
    count+=1
    writer = open('counter.txt',"w")
    writer.write(str(count))
    writer.close()

    time.sleep(d)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your problem is Saving Object in python using pickle , you can simply save the object in pickle and retrieve it according to your conditions. so whenever you will get error just catch the error and dump the number in pickle from where you want start the script. 
You can refer below link.
https://pythonprogramming.net/python-pickle-module-save-objects-serialization.

Comment: How `pickle` is going to help in this case? Which object you will store? OP wants to download the images from URL.

Comment: oh i understands now ! can you check once that url has some filter in it in  which you can pass starting point to ending point as filter params.

Comment: @hi anmol as you can see the end lines in my code. I am creating the pickle object and also loading the same. Can you please modify the code as per your suggestions? I am getting a little confused about dumping the number in pickle thing